# ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.JacksonFeature in Spring boot, upgrading from Elasticsearch HLRC to Java API Client

Tags: spring-boot, maven, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I wanted to swap out the deprecated High Level Rest Client with the new Java API Client from Elasticsearch. Problem is, I'm not sure if my dependencies are configured correctly! I'm running into this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/JacksonFeature
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.JacksonFeature
```

Elasticsearch just got upgraded to 7.17.3 and Spring Boot is 2.2.8 right now, it will be upgraded later but I'm not sure if that's the problem? Here are my dependencies in the pom:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.17.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I followed the documentation from [Elasticsearch here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/7.17/installation.html) so I tried it with the 2.12.3 version of jackson-databind as well but the error persists. Any idea on what should be changed? Thanks!

Edit: just in case it helps, here's also my client which is where the dependency is needed (I assume)

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchClient{

   RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200)).build();
   ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
   public ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
}
```

(I had to put the public in front of client because it sits under another package and won't let me call on it unless it's there)

more info after playing around: turns out there is a parent and it would load an older jackson-databind, so I did the following

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion> 
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
</dependency>
```

still doesn't work so I'm 200% out of ideas now

Answer (score 6):

Add jackson-core solved my problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I did have to add jackson-annotations to

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I updated the core version to :

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.15.2</version>
</dependency>
```